# How does Linux kernel parse vga= parameter?

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to boot my Linux 3.18.48 compiled from source, with resolution 640x480. So I'm passing it a parameter vga=0x312. For some reason, it doesn't work.

To understand what's happening, I grep'ed the kernel source for "vga=", expecting some macro __setup("vga=", function_ptr), similar to other kernel cmdline parameters (video=, root=, etc).
However, there's no such occurrence.

So how does the Linux kernel parse vga= parameter?

Comment: How did you come up with a value of *"vga=0x312"*?  AFAICT there is no VESA BIOS mode 0x212.  Did you try a kernel parameter of `vga=ask` for a menu?

Comment: @sawdust I suspected it was the correct value after reading this: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Framebuffer-HOWTO/x168.html. vga=ask doesn't show me a menu at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt):

```
vga=        [BOOT,X86-32] Select a particular video mode
            ...
            This is actually a boot loader parameter; the value is
            passed to the kernel using a special protocol.
```

So the kernel does not parse this parameter at all. In my case it's GRUB 2.02 parsing this parameter and passing to the kernel through variable `gfxpayload`, as listed in GRUB's [linux command](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/loader/i386/linux.c?h=grub-2.02&id=e54c99aaff5e5f6f5d3b06028506c57e66d8ef77#n883).

Now I can continue investigating why vga= parameter is being ignored, looking at GRUB's source :-)

**EDIT**

vga= is parsed by GRUB only on [legacy BIOS systems](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/loader/i386/linux.c#n882).

That's why vga= is being ignored on my machine. Since I'm using a UEFI system, I need to set the `gfxpayload` variable directly:

```
set gfxpayload=640x480
```

Now it sets the resolution correctly.

Comment: Hi, where did you put the `set gfxpayload=640x480` statement?

Comment: In grub.cfg, @ChanKim

Comment: ok I'l try it tomorrow. I tried GFXPAYLOAD_LINNUX=1920x1080x32 today to no avail. In my case there is no driver for the intel graphic chip (inside the CPU) so I guess it won't work either.

Comment: I believe it's case sensitive. Also, I'm not sure if there's such option with '_LINNUX' suffix. If nothing works, I believe it deserves asking a new question.